# Ubuntu Natty: 32-bit userland, 64-bit kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, kernel, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to manually install a 64-bit kernel for 32-bit Ubuntu. I have my reasons for doing so, but they're too complicated to explain here. Prior to Natty, this worked fine. Now, on Natty, I get the following error message when I try doing it the same way:

```
dsimcha@dsimcha-laptop:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture linux-image-2.6.38-8-server_2.6.38-8.42_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for dsimcha:
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.38-8-server_2.6.38-8.42_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server_2.6.38-8.42_amd64.deb
dsimcha@dsimcha-laptop:~$ cd Downloads/
dsimcha@dsimcha-laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture linux-image-2.6.38-8-server_2.6.38-8.42_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
(Reading database ... 159153 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 2.6.38-8.42 (using linux-image-2.6.38-8-server_2.6.38-8.42_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Unpacking replacement linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.38-8-server /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.38-8-server /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64:
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6).
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 depends on coreutils | fileutils (>= 4.0); however:
Package coreutils:amd64 is not installed.
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 depends on module-init-tools (>= 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3); however:
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 depends on wireless-crda; however:
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-2.6.38-8-server:amd64
```

When I try the dependencies manually, I get, for example:

```
dsimcha@dsimcha-laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
dpkg: error processing coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb (--install):
coreutils:amd64 8.5-1ubuntu6 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with coreutils:i386 8.5-1ubuntu6 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

Has anyone had any success installing 64-bit kernels on 32-bit Natty? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Yeah... Debian et alia haven't got multiarch quite down right. You're going to have to move to the other side if you want this to work correctly.

Comment: Perhaps if you try and explain your **real** aim, we might be able to help you solve that instead. Twice the opportunity for a usable answer, twice the probability you'll get one?